# Why doesn't this QUERY + TRANSPOSE + FILTER work when getting rid of blanks in Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying it with:
`=query(transpose(FILTER(A1:J2;A1:A2=$B$6));"select * where Col1 is not null")`

but it shows multiple rows in the first row.

Here's the practical [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit#gid=231190384)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only transposed once. I recommend using TOROW to get rid of blanks.

Try:

```
=TOROW(FILTER(A1:J2;A1:A2=$B$6);1)
```

Comment: I had to wrap it in `TRANSPOSE()` to achieve my result. Awesome! Thanks!